# In Overlord, did Ainz's friends intentionally make the Nazarick employees sadistic and cruel?

Tags: overlord

A lot of the maids and other NPCs of Nazarick enjoy torture, death, and watching others suffer. Were they intentionally created that way by the original users, Ainz's friends, or was it a result of something else?

Comment: They were roleplaying as villains, so I'm 100% positive they were made intentionally with those settings, the only good aligned NPC being Sebas, who was made by resident White Knight Touch Me, which is why he strives for chivalry,

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if that was intentional by Ainz's friends. It was a game, after all.

Comment: There are a few others that don't have a sadistic and cruel nature if you look at the bios on the wiki